# Unable to Sort ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> by Single HashMap object field in Java Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

i am adding data to ArrayList < HashMap < String, Object>> contactList;

i want to sort the contactList as per their single field .

i am adding data like this :

```
HashMap<String, Object> docs = new HashMap<>();
                        docs.put("name", key);
                        docs.put("speciality", speci);
                        docs.put("status", status);  // sort by this field , if contains online it should appear first .
                        docs.put("picture", bp);
                        docs.put("education", educate);
                        docs.put("experience", experi);
                        docs.put("rating", ft);
                        contactList.add(docs);
```

data is added in a loop and later i assign contactList to simpleAdapter for listview.

Now i want my contact list to compare the 'status' field , if status is 'online' show first or if all status are offline do nothing just show all ;

how can i sort my data , i need to use this data later in listView to show online status contacts first in listview. Any help Would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: i tried this solution but no success http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342658/sort-arraylisthashmapstring-string-using-value

Comment: Couldn't you just use another set or map for online status? Instead of time complexity, growing heap is better solution i guess.

Comment: actually the structure used in code is according to this pattern . so i am bound to trigger some workaround to bring those maps object first whose status value is online in listview by simpleadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a comparator by `anonymous inner class` and sort based on value of `status` field assuming it's always going to be a `String`, e.g.:

```
contactList.sort(new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
        if(null != o1.get("status") && null != o1.get("status")){
            return o2.get("status").toString().compareTo(o1.get("status").toString());
        }else if(null != o1.get("status")){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

You can use `Collections.sort` if `list.sort` is not compatible with current API version, e.g.:

```
Collections.sort(contactList, new Comparator<Map<String, Object>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, Object> o1, Map<String, Object> o2) {
            if(null != o1.get("status") && null != o1.get("status")){
                return o2.get("status").toString().compareTo(o1.get("status").toString());
            }else if(null != o1.get("status")){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where are you checking the status contains value online||offline ..?

Comment: In the comparison, I am comparing `o2` to `o1` which means `online` status will always get sorted before `offline` due to reverse alphabetical ordering

Comment: How can i do this below api 24 ... ? contactList.sort( requires api 24  current min api 18

Comment: You can change the API version as per this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio

Comment: changing api will not allow the app to run on lower platforms ? is it ?

Comment: It should allow the app to run on lower version as the API will be backward compatible. Could you share the `import` statements and exact error message with line?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try removing `@Override` if that's what is causing the issue.

Comment: Added another method, try now?